# Sort the digits of a numerical string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to *SORT* all the digits from some string values in Postgres.

For instance, if I have two strings, e.g.

```
"70005" ==> "00057"
"70001" ==> "00017"
"32451" ==> "12345"
```

I can't cast the strings to integer or bigint due to my logic limitations. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: So you want to sort the digits of a string?

Comment: what are the restrictions for source string. Fixed length? Can start with 0? Give more examples Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Yes William, I need to sort the digits in a string.            Juan: Its a 10 digit string as in like a mobile number . So for explaination purposes, I have used 70005 and 70001. If I input the string as 70005 and 70001 my final output should be 00057 and 00017. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: About how many values do you need to sort? 100? 10,000? 1,000,000?

Comment: When you say you have two string... you mean two rows? and each produce his own result or the combine of both string produce a single result?

Comment: @WilliamKunkel : The string value would be 10 digit {For eg: 9876543210 } and the number of rows would depend on source systems. As of now I have more than 2 million records but it would keep on increasing. Juan : I have more than 2 million records and as of now lets say there is a value '9876543210' in one of the columns and I need that to be sorted .

Comment: See how one aditional example case would help a lot to explain what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive cte. Take the first char. if is `'0'` ignore it other wise go to the begining of `target` string.

Then use LPAD to append `0` until you get length 10.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9627)**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, source, target) as (
    SELECT 1 as id, '70001' as source , '' as target
    UNION 
    SELECT 2 as id, '70005' as source , '' as target
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,
         substring(source from 2 for length(source)-1) as source, 
         CASE WHEN substring(source from 1 for 1) = '0' THEN target
              ELSE substring(source from 1 for 1) || target
         END
    FROM cte
    WHERE length(source) > 0
), reverse as (
    SELECT id, 
           target, 
           row_number() over (partition by id 
                              order by length(target) desc) rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT id, LPAD(target::text, 10, '0')
FROM reverse
WHERE rn = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id |       lpad |
|----|------------|
|  1 | 0000000017 |
|  2 | 0000000057 |
```

Comment: This is very impressive. I would move the data out of the query and into a table, however.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data is organized like this:

```
Table: strings

| id | string  |
|----+---------|
| 1  | '70005' |
| 2  | '70001' |
 etc...
```

Then you can use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT all_digits.id,
       array_to_string(array_agg(all_digits.digit ORDER BY all_digits.digit), '')
FROM (
    SELECT strings.id, digits.digit
    FROM strings, unnest(string_to_array(strings.string, NULL)) digits(digit)
) all_digits
GROUP BY all_digits.id
```

What this query does is split your table up into one row for each character in the string, sorts the table, and then aggregates the characters back into a string.

There's a SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7f7fb0/14

Comment: This is why OP should work harder with the examples. I understand a totally different thing and got the exact result.